# Pasar resultado de JSON a una tabla

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
 function pres(m,s,p) {
 peticionDatos(
   '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/nombres/ejemplo/datos',
     {m:m, s:s, p:p},
       function(){mostrarCuadroProceso(0);},
       function(datos){
       console.log(datos); 
       $(function () {

           $("#nombres tbody tr").each(function (index){

               $(this).children("td").each(function (index2){

                   $(".cuadro").css("background-color", "#ECF8E0");

                   $(".cuadro").html(datos);
               })
           })
       }) 

    });
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que e cada celda que tenga a clase `cuadro` se le asigne el valor que trae el `json`, en consola me imprime datos y me muestra mi el resultado del `json` pero como puedo hacer que me ponga l resultado en la celda,

`$(".cuadro").html(datos);`

esto es lo que me devuelve el JSON

```
{presio: "627.1000000000003"}]
0
:
{presio: "627.1000000000003"}
presio
:
"627.1000000000003"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahí se ve como me imprime el resultado en consola 
En el controlador convierto el resultado en JSON

```
public function presios(){  
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($this->datos_model->data());
    }
```

solamente un registro, que en este caso está en datos que se imprime en la consola.

utilizo `jquery` Alguien  que me pueda ayudar¿?

Comment: te puedo ayudar pero necesito que coloques el json completo ese json tiene problemas de sintaxis                        Error: Parse error on line 1:
..."627.1000000000003"}]0:{"presio": "62
-----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', got ']'

Comment: @JavierAntonioAguayoAguilar error en que esta el error, agregué la linea  donde lo convierto en json que es mi controlador

Comment: no amigo lo que digo que es JSON no esta correctamente escrito , copia y pegalo completo , esa no es la sintaxis correcta , lo coloque en un editor de JSON y tiene problemas de sintaxis

Comment: {presio: "627.1000000000003"}]
0
:
{presio: "627.1000000000003"}
presio
:
"627.1000000000003" eso no esta bien , copia y pegalo completo para poder ayudarte

Comment: @JavierAntonioAguayoAguilar  agregué el controlador donde convierto el resultado de mi  `query` en este caso mi modelo y luego esta la `funcion pres` que llama el resultado

Comment: @JavierAntonioAguayoAguilar agregué una imagen de como es que lo imprime en consola

Comment: la palabra es precio :D

Comment: ¿Alguna solución te fue de utilidad?

Comment: @fredyfx  no, los solucione de una manera diferente

Comment: en ese caso, redacta la solución que has creado, márcala como aceptada y así ayudas a mantener la salud del sitio. Del mismo modo ayudas a una gran cantidad de desarrolladores que tienen la misma pregunta y/o algo similar. Saludos :D

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo un ejemplo que se adapta a lo que buscas:

De este sitio: http://www.json-generator.com/ pude extrar datos para el ejemplo

```js
function GenerarTablaDesdeJson() {
//Con esto borramos la data que haya, evitando agregar N veces lo mismo
$("#resultado").html("");
var InfoDeEjemplo = [
  [{
    "_id": "5984d890a70ff9f57fcd1d08",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "e2457908-e0de-402b-af25-2b111b06dbad",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,844.85",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 23,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": {
      "first": "Hammond",
      "last": "Mercer"
    },
    "company": "MAGNEMO",
    "email": "hammond.mercer@magnemo.tv",
    "phone": "+1 (859) 558-3239",
    "address": "772 Metropolitan Avenue, Lumberton, New York, 5461",
    "about": "Cupidatat occaecat eu cillum ad nulla duis. Mollit minim dolore quis quis nostrud ut excepteur adipisicing ipsum commodo dolor magna. Ex excepteur voluptate cupidatat incididunt quis excepteur cupidatat aliqua ea sit consequat velit.",
    "registered": "Sunday, May 11, 2014 6:27 PM",
    "latitude": "8.005387",
    "longitude": "-172.622234"
  }, {
    "_id": "5984d890985ab8d6d6dcec53",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "cd35e769-18ef-439a-bc97-1469c1e798fc",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$2,036.05",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 29,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Snyder",
      "last": "Shaffer"
    },
    "company": "PHOTOBIN",
    "email": "snyder.shaffer@photobin.net",
    "phone": "+1 (927) 479-2000",
    "address": "926 Plymouth Street, Sanborn, Maine, 526",
    "about": "Laboris magna aliqua deserunt occaecat ullamco velit sint do excepteur sint ipsum adipisicing id magna. Aliqua veniam anim eiusmod elit aliquip aliquip quis eu ea. Dolore officia voluptate aute magna velit. Et veniam irure tempor amet ut aute ea.",
    "registered": "Monday, November 7, 2016 12:23 AM",
    "latitude": "-32.800713",
    "longitude": "82.076508"
  }, {
    "_id": "5984d89077e69b31d7a8c056",
    "index": 2,
    "guid": "daf51e0f-b251-4f9f-81d4-b9be16f1e939",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$2,881.13",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 36,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Rogers",
      "last": "Holcomb"
    },
    "company": "HOMELUX",
    "email": "rogers.holcomb@homelux.biz",
    "phone": "+1 (880) 561-2200",
    "address": "542 Suydam Place, Bowmansville, Vermont, 8121",
    "about": "Eiusmod labore ad cillum dolore voluptate enim. Eu nisi ut ullamco est ut non. Eiusmod non commodo tempor aute minim proident ea ea nostrud exercitation ipsum mollit in cillum. Tempor sint officia commodo sit commodo anim ut tempor velit pariatur anim culpa. Minim officia reprehenderit commodo cupidatat proident elit est laborum consectetur labore voluptate aute duis ut. Laboris occaecat nostrud irure ut quis labore dolore mollit et amet ad ex.",
    "registered": "Thursday, November 6, 2014 1:12 AM",
    "latitude": "68.424218",
    "longitude": "45.178904"
  }, {
    "_id": "5984d890c3acf6b6266c8b18",
    "index": 3,
    "guid": "d5e8fa61-c67a-4af2-935c-a9de8573e263",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$2,823.44",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 28,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Bird",
      "last": "Macdonald"
    },
    "company": "DUFLEX",
    "email": "bird.macdonald@duflex.name",
    "phone": "+1 (843) 411-2062",
    "address": "290 Manor Court, Coldiron, Louisiana, 5600",
    "about": "Quis dolor enim ullamco incididunt adipisicing. Aliquip reprehenderit est fugiat sit exercitation culpa sit irure. Non elit Lorem ipsum velit ad ea duis sunt amet.",
    "registered": "Monday, April 21, 2014 5:10 AM",
    "latitude": "-49.918643",
    "longitude": "143.96742"
  }, {
    "_id": "5984d890feeeaeff774a2e6b",
    "index": 4,
    "guid": "d26abfb5-d7e9-462d-9a94-d065edbd7b86",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,597.15",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Hamilton",
      "last": "Young"
    },
    "company": "NAVIR",
    "email": "hamilton.young@navir.co.uk",
    "phone": "+1 (888) 555-3667",
    "address": "201 Crystal Street, Galesville, Rhode Island, 3530",
    "about": "Incididunt nulla culpa pariatur duis culpa ullamco irure. Quis non esse irure id culpa minim proident fugiat ad ex nisi Lorem. Aliquip tempor cillum officia nulla incididunt fugiat deserunt cillum fugiat aliquip.",
    "registered": "Saturday, June 18, 2016 2:56 AM",
    "latitude": "80.706515",
    "longitude": "54.423457"
  }, {
    "_id": "5984d8901c74779b3fce22d2",
    "index": 5,
    "guid": "2e3915b4-23ca-4230-af4c-fdd37d0c4e28",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$3,464.37",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 32,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": {
      "first": "Preston",
      "last": "Gay"
    },
    "company": "RECRITUBE",
    "email": "preston.gay@recritube.us",
    "phone": "+1 (897) 423-2742",
    "address": "315 Lynch Street, Alleghenyville, New Mexico, 4505",
    "about": "Officia duis magna quis in ipsum do ipsum enim sit et non commodo ut. Sit sit officia cupidatat exercitation et duis deserunt in Lorem eiusmod in. Nisi id adipisicing consectetur Lorem sint.",
    "registered": "Friday, December 18, 2015 10:08 PM",
    "latitude": "-32.601154",
    "longitude": "-175.226687"
  }, {
    "_id": "5984d8901c33a4f31d61d966",
    "index": 6,
    "guid": "9b3abcec-c3fc-47cb-864b-b6733da8758b",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$3,552.51",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 27,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Brittany",
      "last": "Dyer"
    },
    "company": "EXTRAGENE",
    "email": "brittany.dyer@extragene.biz",
    "phone": "+1 (898) 459-3797",
    "address": "307 Virginia Place, Garfield, Mississippi, 1242",
    "about": "Occaecat minim amet enim id duis exercitation velit aliquip minim cillum culpa. In laborum mollit sit dolor consectetur anim Lorem qui cillum irure proident sit amet. Aliqua incididunt cupidatat occaecat exercitation eu aute labore Lorem in. Minim nostrud elit occaecat non ex aute exercitation. Ea ea enim enim magna.",
    "registered": "Sunday, June 21, 2015 8:07 AM",
    "latitude": "37.142702",
    "longitude": "-126.37982"
  }, {
    "_id": "5984d890ccbd9bc24ee5a140",
    "index": 7,
    "guid": "ce341b3c-35fb-47be-b83d-a872ec525e99",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,124.24",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 38,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": {
      "first": "Lucille",
      "last": "Delgado"
    },
    "company": "HYDROCOM",
    "email": "lucille.delgado@hydrocom.com",
    "phone": "+1 (945) 455-3803",
    "address": "593 High Street, Bartonsville, New Hampshire, 5790",
    "about": "Veniam veniam velit dolore commodo amet aute exercitation exercitation consectetur laboris. Exercitation eiusmod aliqua in consequat. Nisi id dolore sint officia ea fugiat aliqua aliqua. Magna proident nisi proident nulla esse laboris.",
    "registered": "Monday, June 8, 2015 3:08 AM",
    "latitude": "30.092179",
    "longitude": "-34.088397"
  }, {
    "_id": "5984d8904d297beb9d48fdaf",
    "index": 8,
    "guid": "d5e22bad-bd5a-4682-8df7-253a5a32ac78",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,912.90",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 31,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Georgette",
      "last": "Burris"
    },
    "company": "QUINEX",
    "email": "georgette.burris@quinex.info",
    "phone": "+1 (928) 504-3524",
    "address": "587 Verona Place, Sylvanite, South Carolina, 5788",
    "about": "Esse ad et veniam sunt fugiat cillum. Amet laborum voluptate nisi proident cupidatat exercitation nulla anim nulla. Voluptate mollit excepteur commodo ad aliqua. Labore est dolore commodo ea in ullamco eiusmod ut mollit ex Lorem deserunt laboris. Dolore proident mollit reprehenderit Lorem ipsum eiusmod nostrud.",
    "registered": "Monday, May 1, 2017 6:15 PM",
    "latitude": "1.334383",
    "longitude": "175.744176"
  }]
];


  $.each(InfoDeEjemplo, function(key, value) {
    //Es buena practica ver los datos con los que vas a trabajar:
    //console.log(value);
    RenderizarTablaPersonalizada(value);
  });
}

function RenderizarTablaPersonalizada(informationToRender) {
  var table = $("#resultado");
  //rowIndex = Indice de Fila, 
  //r = es el valor de cada fila
  $.each(informationToRender, function(rowIndex, r) {
    var row = $("<tr/>");
    //colIndex = Indice de columna
    //c = es el valor de la columna
    $.each(r, function(colIndex, c) {
      //De todo el Json, seleccionamos las columnas que deseamos mostrar
      if (colIndex == "guid" || colIndex == "age" || colIndex == "phone" || colIndex == "address") {
        row.append($("<td/>").text(c));
      }
    });
    //Luego de agregar todas las columnas con informacion, ahora vamos a gregar un boton que contendra un clasico onclick:

    row.append($("<td/>")
      .append($('<button/>', {
        text: 'Seleccionar',
        click: function() {
          alert("¡Saludos hermandad de SOes! \n el GUID de este elemento es: " + r.guid);
        }
      })));
    table.append(row);
  });

}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="GenerarTablaDesdeJson();" value="Generar Tabla desde Json" />
<br/><br/>

<div>
  <table cellspacing="0">
    <colgroup>
      <col>
        <col>
          <col>
            <col>
              <col>
    </colgroup>
    <thead class="">
      <tr>
        <th class="" scope="col">GUID</th>
        <th class="" scope="col">Edad</th>
        <th class="" scope="col">Telefono</th>
        <th class="" scope="col">Direccion</th>
        <th class="" scope="col">Operaciones</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="resultado">

    </tbody>
  </table>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con `$(".cuadro").html(datos.presio);` ya que los elementos que tienen la clase 'cuadro' son *td*

Para acceder al valor que viene en datos seria `datos.presio`

`$(".cuadro")` al realizar esto un mismo dato estaría contenido en todos los elementos que contengan la clase *cuadro*

[jquery val w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp)

por otra parte si puedes mostrar el json que esta contenido en **datos**

Acá puedes ver un ejemplo la diferencia entre `.html()` - `.text()` - `.val()` de Jquery
[codepen ejemplo html vs text vs val de Jquery](https://codepen.io/itsthomas/pen/WvegvM)

Comment: la clase cuadro esta en los td de una tabla son celdas, l puse para así cada celda que tenga esa clase recibiera un color y el dato del JSON , e actualizado mi pregunta y puse que es lo que me devuelve el JSON

Comment: Ya actualice mi respuesta, para acceder al dato que retorna el json en la variable datos; debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera `datos.presio`

Comment: pero al hacer eso lo unico que me pinta en la tabla es un `-`

Comment: escapa en la consola `datos.presio` a ver que imprime

Comment: Me imprime esto 
`[{presio: "11.36"}]
0
:
{presio: "11.36"}
presio
:
"11.36"`

Comment: eso que mostraste es la variable datos completa. Que es lo mismo que se ve en el retorno del json.
Imprime esto `console.log(datos.presio);`

Comment: si eso mismo tal cual la puse y me imprime lo mismo